# How can i read web page formulas, normally?

Tags: latex

Sorry if this is not really superuser question. but I really couldnt find an answer on internet. http://www.pandasthumb.org/archives/2004/05/shannon_entropy.html I am trying to read this page but all formulas are displayed as text. what should i do to see them as formulas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn basic [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) syntax and render it in your head (not that hard for the basics, really) -- presumably the target audience of this page is expected to be familiar with this notation.

If that doesn't work for you, you can search the web for "online latex renderer" or similar; there are a number of sites that let you paste in a formula, and then render it for you as a graphic.